# Alpha vantage API Not working for NSE while the same query is giving output for foreign stocks

Tags: php, stockquotes, alpha-vantage

I was trying to get JSON for a company by calling API of alphavantage. For some company data it works and for some company it's failing.
For example, for this query it works:

[https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&outputsize=full&apikey={API_KEY}](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&outputsize=full&apikey=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

But for example this query fails:

[https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=NSE:TATAMOTORS&outputsize=full&apikey={API_KEY}](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=NSE:TATAMOTORS&outputsize=full&apikey=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add: What is your question? What is your error? What do you expect SO members to answer?

Comment: The API is not returning any data for NSE stocks. If I'm doing anything wrong or the API is not supporting currently the NSE stocks

Comment: @S.Roy:  API documentation should be able to help for both of your queries. Check the docs whether it supports NSE stocks or there's something wrong with the query format. We don't have access to APIs so we won't be able to help much.

Comment: They appear to be having some technical issues [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62574002/2710413)

Comment: Try dropping them an email support@alphavantage.co

Comment: yes. Did that. thanks to all

Comment: Let us know the response.

Comment: They have not responded yet. if I get one, i will update here

Answer (score 5):

go to link and search exact code for your stock.
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=tatamotors&apikey=ZZZZZZZZZZZZ

Hope this will help u.

Comment: don't forget to replace keyword value "tatamotors" and API key mentioned on the link.

Comment: Hello PrashantT, instead of commenting on your answer, you can edit it. Comments are easy to overlook when scanning answers, and they're sometimes hidden. It's better to edit/update and answer to make it more complete than adding a comment that may be overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Alphavantage has stopped supporting NSE data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this answer late.

It works for BSE and its in the documentation too.You can try it out like:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=RELIANCE.BSE&outputsize=full&interval=5min&apikey=*your_key*

[ALPHA VANTAGE BSE](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#symbolsearch)

On the other hand,it works for for Daily and Monthly timeframes and not for Intraday :(.